# What is the purpose of the parenthesis in this switch and case label?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

I am writing a function for an item  service where if the user requests for all items under a certain name it will return them all. Such as all the phones that are iPhone X's etc.

I got help to make one of the functions work where if there are more than 1 items it will return them all (this is the third case):

```
var itemsList = items.ToList();

switch (itemsList.Count())
{
    case 0:
        throw new Exception("No items with that model");

    case 1:
        return itemsList;

    case { } n when n > 1:
        return itemsList;
}

return null;
```

What confuses me is what are the `{ }` for? I was told it was "a holding place as sub for stating the type" I am unsure of what they mean by this.

How does it work too? I am not sure what `n` is for.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

PROGRESS: After following up with the helper, I now know that `{ }` is similar to `var`. But I am still unsure why it is only used here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a capability of [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/may/csharp-8-0-pattern-matching-in-csharp-8-0) that was introduced in `C# 8`. `{ }` matches any non-null value. `n` is used to declare a variable that will hold matched value. Here is a sample from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/pattern-matching#implement-the-basic-toll-calculations) that shows usage of `{ }`.

Explanation of your sample:

```
switch (itemsList.Count())
{
    case 0:
        throw new Exception("No items with that model");

    case 1:
        return itemsList;

    // If itemsList.Count() != 0 && itemsList.Count() != 1 then it will
    // be checked against this case statement.
    // Because itemsList.Count() is a non-null value, then its value will
    // be assigned to n and then a condition agaist n will be checked.
    // If condition aginst n returns true, then this case statement is
    // considered satisfied and its body will be executed.
    case { } n when n > 1:
        return itemsList;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is known as [`property pattern`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/may/csharp-8-0-pattern-matching-in-csharp-8-0#expressing-patterns). The `{}` deals with remaining *nonnull* objects. Property patterns express a property that needs to have a specific constant value. But, in your example, I think it is just to use `n` in the switch-expression by assuring `n` is not null. I mean its equivalent is as follows.

```
if (itemsList is {} n && n.Count() > 1)
{
    return itemsList;
}
```